# Is my FTP account compromised?

Tags: ftp, certificate

Today I tried to connect to my ftp account with Cyberduck. There was a popup screen saying that I had an "Unsecured FTP connection" and that "The server supports encrypted connections. Do you want to switch to FTP-SSL?". I clicked on the "change" button which led to another popup claiming that the certificate was not trusted.  I didn't take it seriously - I know it was wrong! - and connected to the server. I was trying to download a file, but the file could not be downloaded. I managed to disconnect and connect again several times to download the file, which was to no avail. I decided to read the contents of the certificate upon which I came to know that I did not know the cert. It was not mine, because I had not made any ssl certs at all for my ftp account.

The details of the certificate which is named "localhost" are as follows:

Country: GB
State/provice: Someprovince
Locality: Sometown
Organization: none
Organizational Unit: none
Common name: localhost
Email Address: webaster@localhost
.
.
.

Now my question is if my FTP account is compromised? I changed the password, but I do now know if any malicious codes are injected into my server.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are making unsecured FTP connections, so anyone who can intercept your packets can compromise your account.

Comment: Hi. I know that. But what is the certificate there. That is not mine. I just did not create it.

Comment: It's the server's certificate. The idea is that encryption with no authentication or MITM protection is better than nothing.

Comment: I know it is the server's certificate. I own the VPS but I did not create this cert. Can this be an instance of man-in-the-middle attack?

Comment: @developer It certainly can be. But more likely the server just created a self-signed certificate by default.

Comment: @Schwartz I have just removed all certs (there were two certs there, one ending with .ca) within the folder ssl.crt and the only key in ssl.key folder. However, still when I try to connect through my ftp account, the FTP client advertises that I connect with the fake certificate. How can I get rid of that fake cert?